# Global equivalency config. Excluding members

Tags: c#, .net, nunit, fluent-assertions

I'm wondering if I can do a global config for a test. I know that I can compare this object something like that:

```
x.Should().BeEquivalentTo(y, opt => opt.Excluding(z => z.Member)
```

But I want all the methods in my test to use this config.

Answer (score 2):

To exclude a member from a specific type, you can create a custom [`IMemberSelectionRule`](https://fluentassertions.com/extensibility/#about-selection-matching-and-ordering).

To use that selection rule for all tests, use the static `AssertionOptions.AssertEquivalencyUsing` in some setup method of your unit testing framework.
Be aware that `AssertionOptions.AssertEquivalencyUsing` changes static state of Fluent Assertions, so if you're running tests in parallel it should be invoked before *any* tests are run.
For NUnit that would be `[OneTimeSetUp]` inside a [`[SetUpFixture]`](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/SetUpFixture-Attribute) not inside a namespace.

```cs
using FluentAssertions;
using FluentAssertions.Equivalency;
using NUnit.Framework;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

[SetUpFixture]
public class MySetUpClass
{
    [OneTimeSetUp]
    public void RunBeforeAnyTests()
    {
        AssertionOptions.AssertEquivalencyUsing(e => e.Using(new MyNamespace.MyClassSelectionRule()));
    }
}

namespace MyNamespace
{
    class MyOuterClass
    {
        public MyInnerClass MemberToInclude { get; set; }

        public int MemberToExclude { get; set; }
    }

    class MyInnerClass
    {
        public int AnotherMemberToInclude { get; set; }

        public int MemberToExclude { get; set; }
    }

    internal class MyClassSelectionRule : IMemberSelectionRule
    {
        public bool IncludesMembers => false;

        public IEnumerable<IMember> SelectMembers(INode currentNode, IEnumerable<IMember> selectedMembers, MemberSelectionContext context) =>
            selectedMembers.Where(e => !(e.DeclaringType.Name == nameof(MyOuterClass) && e.Name == nameof(MyOuterClass.MemberToExclude)));
    }

    [TestFixture]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        [Test]
        public void Ignore_the_member_MemberToExclude_on_MyOuterClass()
        {
            var subject = new MyOuterClass
            {
                MemberToInclude = new MyInnerClass
                {
                    AnotherMemberToInclude = 42,
                    MemberToExclude = 42
                },
                MemberToExclude = 1
            };

            var expectation = new MyOuterClass
            {
                MemberToInclude = new MyInnerClass
                {
                    AnotherMemberToInclude = 42,
                    MemberToExclude = 42
                },
                MemberToExclude = 2
            };

            subject.Should().BeEquivalentTo(expectation);
        }

        [Test]
        public void Do_not_ignore_the_member_MemberToExclude_on_MyInnerClass()
        {
            var subject = new MyOuterClass
            {
                MemberToInclude = new MyInnerClass
                {
                    MemberToExclude = 1
                },
            };

            var expectation = new MyOuterClass
            {
                MemberToInclude = new MyInnerClass
                {
                    MemberToExclude = 2
                },
            };

            Action act = () => subject.Should().BeEquivalentTo(expectation);

            act.Should().Throw<AssertionException>();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But be careful with test frameworks that run their tests in parallel. `AssertionOptions` changes the static state.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It works. But how can I check the type? What if I have two classes: `Foo` and `Bar` that have fields with the same name `FieldName`. I want to exclude it from `Foo` but still check it for `Bar`

Comment: @SergеуIsupov I've updated the example to handle multiple types with a member named `MemberToExclude`

Comment: Great answer and exactly what I needed! The signature for `SelectMembers` changed slightly a few years ago, so I updated your code. Thanks!